# Interactively highlighting specific ranges of time series with bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, jscript

I have a simple time series plot.

On top of the time series plot I need a layer that highlights specific ranges. Glyphs come to mind, something like the following:

```
fig.quad(top=[10], bottom=[0], left=[0], right=[100], color="red", fill_alpha = 0.2)
```

Now the user should be able to add/remove such glyphs and adjust their `left` and `right` parameters (preferably by dragging/shifting the left and right borders). The `bottom` and `top` parameters are of no importance and should be `-Inf` and `Inf` respectively. The bokeh server should then save these adjustments.

[`BoxEditTool`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#boxedittool) comes to mind which works with rectangular glyphs, but the functionality I miss is editing `left` and `right` parameters. (I know that I can delete and add a glyph to change left/right parameters, but that is not an option, since zooming in and adjusting the left/right parameters is required).

Any way to interactively adjust the left and right parameters? Or maybe a completely different approach to achieve highlighting specific ranges?

PS I also notice that `BoxEditTool` is very slow/unresponsive on larger time series.

Answer (score 3):

The 0.13 release introduced the `RangeTool`:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, RangeTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL

dates = np.array(AAPL['date'], dtype=np.datetime64)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(date=dates, close=AAPL['adj_close']))

p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=800, tools="", toolbar_location=None,
           x_axis_type="datetime", x_range=(dates[1500], dates[2500]))

p.line('date', 'close', source=source)
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Price'

select = figure(plot_height=150, plot_width=800, y_range=p.y_range,
                x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_type=None,
                tools="", toolbar_location=None)

range_rool = RangeTool(x_range=p.x_range)
range_rool.overlay.fill_color = "navy"
range_rool.overlay.fill_alpha = 0.2

select.line('date', 'close', source=source)
select.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
select.add_tools(range_rool)
select.toolbar.active_multi = range_rool

show(column(p, select))
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting indeed, and thank you for the demo. I am currently experimenting with it, and I don't really see a way to add/remove ranges, nor to link them to `ColumnDataSource`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavorJosipovic, I have tried it as is, but when I set the `x_range=(dates[1500], dates[2500])` I am getting an error. Usually how do we set the x_range in the figure object?